# Second x-axis label not fitting inside figure

Tags: matlab

I am trying to add a second x-axis to a figure. It seems to be working, but the second axis label is displayed half-outside of the figure. That is, I only see the bottom half of "2nd Axis" displayed. Here is a small example to demonstrate the problem:

```
close all;

ax1 = gca;
set(ax1,'XColor','r','YColor','r')
xlabel(ax1, '1st Axis');


data=rand(10,2);
line(data(:,1), data(:,2), 'Color', 'r');

ax2 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),...
           'XAxisLocation','top',...
           'YAxisLocation','right',...
           'Color','none',... % necessary, or the axes do not appear
           'XColor','k','YColor','k');
xlabel(ax2, '2nd Axis');

data=rand(10,2);
line(data(:,1), data(:,2), 'Color', 'k','Parent', ax2);
```

Is there a better way to position the axis label besides 'top'? Or is there a way to say "fit everything inside the figure"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command will help you:
`'ActivePositionProperty','OuterPosition'`
See [this website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/automatic-axes-resize.html) for additional information.
You have to adjust the top axis, using this command:

```
ax2 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),...
       'XAxisLocation','top',...
       'YAxisLocation','right',...
       'Color','none',... % necessary, or the axes do not appear
       'XColor','k','YColor','k','ActivePositionProperty','OuterPosition');
```

If it is not important in which order the plot is assembled, invert it, so that the red axis fits the other one:

```
close all;

ax2 = axes('XAxisLocation','top',...
           'YAxisLocation','right',...
           'XColor','k','YColor','k','ActivePositionProperty','OuterPosition');
xlabel(ax2, '2nd Axis');

data=rand(10,2);
line(data(:,1), data(:,2), 'Color', 'k','Parent', ax2);

ax1 = axes('Position',get(ax2,'Position'),...
           'Color','none',... % necessary, or you do not see the second graph
           'XColor','r','YColor','r');
xlabel(ax1, '1st Axis');

data=rand(10,2);
line(data(:,1), data(:,2), 'Color', 'r');
```

Comment: Hm, I was happy with where the actual axis was, just not the axis label. Using ActivePositionProperty seems to put the label in a better spot (totally inside the figure now), but it moves the axis inside the white part of the plot rather than just on the edge as it should be.

Comment: The full code in your edit works, but I don't understand the difference? Why does the order that the axes are drawn affect the label placement?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a way to set xLabel at best position, I won't trust it, as I don't trust legend('','Location','best').

Two ways in my mind:

```
set(get(ax2,'XLabel'),'Position',get(xlabh,'Position) - [0 .2 0])
```

or

```
ax1 = axes('XColor','r','YColor','r','Position',[0.1 0.1 0.9 0.7]);
```

Comment: Hm, something like that seems to move the label, but I can't seem to get it in the right spot:

xlab2h = xlabel(ax2, '2nd Axis');
set(xlab2h,'Position', get(xlab2h,'Position') - [0 .09 0])

With .1 it is way too far down, with .09 it is half inside the white region, and with .08 it disappears? Also adjusting that value seems to also change the x position?